# Не могу разобраться с полосой прокрутки

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Проблема в том что полоса прокрутки слишком короткая и не могу это настроить(не знаю как)
Вот код:

```
from tkinter import*

def allrezum():
    win = Toplevel(root,relief=SUNKEN,bd=10,bg="lightblue")
    win.title("Дочернее окно")
    win.minsize(width=400,height=200) 


root = Tk()

m = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=m)

fm = Menu(m)
m.add_cascade(label="Резюме",menu=fm)
fm.add_command(label="Все резюме", command = allrezum) 

lab1 = Label(root, text="Новое Резюме", font="Arial 22")
lab2 = Label(root, text="Имя", font="Arial 18")
ent1 = Entry(root,width=20,bd=3)
lab3 = Label(root, text="Фамилия", font="Arial 18")
ent2 = Entry(root,width=20,bd=3)
lab4 = Label(root, text="Город", font="Arial 18")
lab5 = Label(root, text="Страна", font="Arial 18")
lab6 = Label(root, text="Технологический Стек", font="Arial 18")
lab7 = Label(root, text="Должность", font="Arial 18")
ent3 = Entry(root,width=20,bd=3)
lab8 = Label(root, text="Уровень Английского", font="Arial 18")
lab9 = Label(root, text="Комментарии", font="Arial 18")
frame2=Frame(root,bg='red',bd=5)
tex = Text(frame2,width=20,height=5,
          font="Verdana 12",
          wrap=WORD) 
scr = Scrollbar(frame2,command=tex.yview,)
tex.configure(yscrollcommand=scr.set)


sca1 = Scale(root,orient=HORIZONTAL,length=300,
          from_=0,to=100,tickinterval=10,resolution=5)
lab1.grid(row=0, column=1)
lab2.grid(row=1, column=0)
ent1.grid(row=1, column=1)
lab3.grid(row=2, column=0)
ent2.grid(row=2, column=1)
lab4.grid(row=1, column=2)

lab5.grid(row=2, column=2)

lab6.grid(row=4, column=0)

lab7.grid(row=4, column=2)

lab8.grid(row=5, column=0)

lab9.grid(row=4, column=2)
tex.grid(row=5, column=1)
sca1.grid(row=6, column=1)
frame2.grid(row=5, column=1)
scr.grid(row=5, column=2)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать для текстового поля и полосы прокрутки не `grid`, а упаковку внутри их фрейма:

```
frame2=Frame(root,bg='red',bd=5)
tex = Text(frame2,
          width=20, height=5,
          font="Verdana 12",
          wrap=WORD) 

scr = Scrollbar(frame2,command=tex.yview,)

tex.configure(yscrollcommand=scr.set)

scr.pack(side='right', fill='y') # "Прилепить" к правому краю фрейма, заполнять по высоте (ось y)
tex.pack(fill='both') # Упаковать в оставшуюся часть фрейма, заполнять по высоте и ширине (both)
```

Ниже в коде нужно убрать строки `tex.grid(row=5, column=1)` и `scr.grid(row=5, column=2)`, так как мы эти элементы управления уже расположили при помощи `pack`. Если не убрать, будет выдавать ошибку такого вида:

> _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside .47534160 which already has slaves managed by pack

Результат:

[image: Скриншот]

Для сравнения, как полоса прокрутки выглядела до изменений:

[image: Скриншот]

**Обновление**

Альтернативный вариант с размещением элементов в фрейме при помощи `grid`:

```
tex.grid(row=0, column=0)
scr.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)  # Растягивать полосу прокрутки вверх и вниз
```

Визуально не отличается от размещения при помощи `pack`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!